# What does selecting a badge in the profile view in the scanner do?

Tags: ingress

I have recently managed to *select* badges in my profile. It happens if you press and hold on a badge for a couple of seconds. They appear with yellow brackets around them. It's possible to select multiple ones. I could not reproduce it on Android and iPhone.

The selection shows up on the share-button screenshot, but disappears afterwards.

There seems to be no apparent action possible with this. Does anyone know what this is for?

[image: Selected badges in scanner]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll eventually be able to rearrange medals, but I can't remember if that's just speculation or officially announced off the top of my head. At the moment there's no use for it that I know of, except highlighting badges when sharing.